Limiting the scope of re.sub
Suppose I have a long 'mystring' and I have already removed all of its line feeds.
startpattern   some unneeded data endpattern Juicy Data Block 1 startpattern   more unneeded data  endpattern Juicy Data Block 2 

I want to use re.sub to grab both Juicy Data Blocks
re.sub(r'startpattern.+endpattern','',mystring) 

but of course the problem is the greedy lookahead will remove the first section of data I need, only leaving the Juicy Data Block 2 section.  Adding a count=1 argument to the re.sub doesn't solve the greedy lookahead.  How to best go about capturing all the data I need?  Should I be splitting instead of the startpattern.+endpattern bookends and operating on sections or can re.sub do this?

By default . doesn't match newlines. So .+ will not cross a line boundary, and this should do what you want.

I clarified I have already stripped out all the \n from the long string by editing the OP.

Use non-greedy .+??

That works, thanks.

Yes the other article is similar, so this can be safely labeled as a duplicate.

Note in my scenario since I know the bookends occur twice, I can run re.sub in a non-greedy mode twice to do what I want.

Python non-greedy regexes gives the basics, which is to add a ? to my original attempt.  Thus .+? inside the re.sub.  Then, to do what I want, since the start/end bookends occur twice, run my modified re.sub twice.
